# Why does the Django development server hang on this admin tool JS file?

Tags: django, django-admin

Periodically, when using the Django admin tool, it hangs and stops responding to requests until it is restarted. Whenever it hangs, the last line in the log is:

> "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2158

The hang seems to occur after a POST (like when viewing the results of adding an object). It happens with a variety of different models and is unpredictable, as far as I can tell. The only constant is the GET request to that Javascript file. Also, the time between hangs varies: sometimes you can add objects with the admin tool for an hour, sometimes it can't last 5 minutes.

Performance-wise, the box does not appear to be under much stress (load average of 0.17-0.20)

[EDIT]
It recently output an error that looks interesting, though it recovered itself and kept serving responses afterwards:

```
[18/Aug/2011 13:19:50] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2158
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
self.finish_response()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 420, in write
self._write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 300, in write
self.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 286, in flush
self._sock.sendall(buffer)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because of you using Google Chrome. Which will make more then one connection to a web-server, which in the case of the Django Dev server it's no good. You have two options. 
Either use

- [Django Concurrent Server](https://github.com/ashchristopher/django-concurrent-server)
- Setup your dev-server using a production server (Don't recommend, more complex)
- Use Firefox, tell Chrome to stop multiple connections
- Host your static files on your computer using a separate server. Like Lighttpd or something.